# Efficiently transform and blend images in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm making a program to simulate brush strokes with a given image, and I'm held up the actual putting the brush strokes down part. Right now I'm using OpenCV and Numpy to rotate and mix images together by setting a section of the original image to be the new one. Here's the current code.

```py
def rotate(img, deg):
    """Rotates an image a certain number of degrees"""
    h, w, c = img.shape
    matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((w / 2, h / 2), deg, 1)
    out = cv2.warpAffine(img, matrix, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

    return out
   
def paste(img1, img2, mask, x, y):
    """Pastes one image on top of another at a given location"""
    h1, w1, _ = img1.shape  # dimensions of original image
    h2, w2, _ = img2.shape  # dimensions of pasted image

    if y > h1 or x > w1:
        return img1

    stamp = img2
    factor = mask

    subx = ((w2 + x) - w1)
    suby = ((h2 + y) - h1)

    if suby <= 0:
        suby = 0
    if subx <= 0:
        subx = 0

    stamp = img2[0:h2 - suby, 0:w2 - subx]
    factor = mask[0:h2 - suby, 0:w2 - subx]
    snippet = img1[y:y + (h2 - suby), x:x + (w2 - subx)]

    stamp = cv2.add(cv2.multiply(snippet, (1-factor)), cv2.multiply(stamp, factor))
    out = img1
    out[y:y + h2, x:x + w2] = stamp

    return out
```

It works, but only barely. There are issues that come up with certain scenarios, it's very limited as to what you're allowed to do with it, and is extremely slow. **Is there an easier/better way to transform and blend images with OpenCV, or would a different framework (sprite/object based, like pygame) be better for this?** Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try seamless cloning. Check this excellent tutorial from Satya Mallick: https://www.learnopencv.com/seamless-cloning-using-opencv-python-cpp/

In this case you can substitute the plane in the tutorial for your brush.